# How to do this feature? (What's the name of this feature?)

Tags: linux, makefile, configuration, cmake, hevc

When I built `x265` today, I found a fancy feature as the following picture.

[image]

Here comes the question, what can the feature be named? And how can we realize this feature?

ps. Forgive me for the helpless title and tags. It's a great favor if someone can help me to tag this question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "feature" is [ccmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/ccmake.1.html) program.

Aside from normal `cmake` functionality it provides possibility to edit CMake Cache with curses interface.